# Finding the different numbers whose sum squares give a number which has same digits

Tags: number-theory

I could find the following numbers

> $$1+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2=55$$ $$1+4^2+7^2=66$$ $$2^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+11^2+13^2+17^2=666$$

Are there other numbers ?

Comment: That number of the Beast (lol) is particularly cool, the numbers squared in the LHS are the first 7 primes.

Comment: You can choose 1 5 14 or 1 10 11 or 2 7 13 or 1 3 4 14 or 1 4 6 13 or 1 6 8 11 or 2 4 9 11 or 2 5 7 12 or 3 7 8 10 or 4 5 9 10 or 4 6 7 11 or 1 2 3 8 12 or 1 2 6 9 10 or 1 4 5 6 12 or 2 3 4 7 12 or 4 5 6 8 9 to generate 222 (there are _a lot_ more for generating something as large as 666).

Comment: And based on my experiments, the _only_ numbers (based on @GerryMyerson's comment) that do _not_ permit such a solution are: 11, 22, 33, and 44.

Comment: Anything to say/ask about the answers you've had, Ehegh?

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear what is wanted here. As I noted in the comments, Bateman [proved](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa67/aa6745.pdf) that, given any $s\ge5$, every sufficiently large integer is a sum of $s$ distinct squares. Also, the Online [Encyclopedia](http://oeis.org/A001422) of Integer Sequences has the complete list of numbers that cannot be expressed as a sum of distinct squares; the largest is 128. But OP's examples have more structure; the first two, the numbers being squared are in arithmetic progression and start with 1; the third, the numbers being squared are the first few primes. Maybe OP will clarify just what conditions are wanted here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in fact, every natural number is the sum of four squares: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem

Sorry if I have killed the magic (it was Lagrange, not me) :) Your third sum is still very nice.

Comment: What about squares of different numbers asked by OP?

Comment: Lagrange did not prove that infinitely many multiples of $11$ can be written as the sum of a number of squares.

Comment: If it is true (which it obviously is) that every natural number can be a sum of four squares, then it's true that any number you choose (e.g. 11, 22, 33, 555, etc.) can be expressed as a sum of four squares.  However, if the condition is that they be _distinct_ squares, then it is likely a more challenging problem...and note that the if you lift the requirement of four squares, this becomes trivial: you could simply choose $1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + ...$

Comment: My question if the numbers are different

Comment: Bateman proved that, given any $s\ge5$, every asufficiently large integer is a sum of $s$ distinct squares. http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa67/aa6745.pdf  Also, http://oeis.org/A001422 has the complete list of numbers which cannot be expressed as a sum of distinct squares; the largest is 128.

Comment: As @GerryMyerson states, there are actually _numerous_ sums of (distinct) squares which give almost any number.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You should really provide your comment as an answer because, to me, you have actually answered the question while this answer that you are commenting on completely misses the point.